# Jackson ObjectMapper write Object twice with different values

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

i would like to write simple object into json twice.
First object should have all values. Second Object should set everytime a 0 on one field.
Expected result:

> {    [
> {
> "time":"3",
> "name": "steve"
> },
> {
> "time":"0",
> "name": "steve"
> },    ]  }

And my class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@JsonSerialize(using = DoubleSerializer.class)
public class MyClass{

    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    @JsonPropertyDescription("my value")
    private long time;

    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    @JsonPropertyDescription("my name")
    private String name;

}
```

I've  tried to use @JsonSerialize(using = DoubleSerializer.class) on MyClass,

```
public class DoubleSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Vereinigungen> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(MyClass value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        String origObject = value.toString();
        value.setValue(0);
        String copyObject = value.toString();
        gen.writeString(origObject.concat(copyObject));
    }
}
```

but, it generates not valid json:

```
MyClass myClass = MyClass.builder().name("Steve").value("20").build();
ObjectMapperFactory.getJacksonMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(myClass);
```

how can i cancat this. Maybe it is a wrong approach.

Comment: I think it also depends on what you are trying to avhieve. I think you can't do this in the generic way you are aiming to because you are trying to convert an object into an array. If this has to be returned by another object or by a rest controller, maybe there is something you can do there.

Comment: Instead of using a custom serializer I'd provide an array of `MyObject` instances which contains the original instance as well as a _copy_ (with `time` set to 0). Additionally you might need a wrapper or at least some settings in the object mapper to create the outer json object instead of having an array at the root.